# Initialization of inner python class, module or function scope

Tags: python, class, scoping

The following code prints `a1 m` with python2, python3, jython, and pypy. Thus, I assume it is wanted behavior. However, I do not understand why in `C1` class scope `x` is evaluated using the surrounding function scope, while in `C2` the following `x = x` makes the preceding `x` evaluate using the surrounding module scope.

```
x = "m"
def a1():
    x = "a1"
    class C1(object):
        print(x)
a1()
def a2():
    x = "a2"
    class C2(object):
        print(x)
        x = x
a2()
```

Using in an additional inner function the line `x = x` is a syntax error, which is fine. But in an inner class within a function this seems to be acceptable, although with a rather weird semantics?

Answer (score 1):

When you define a variable within a class definition, you are really assigning an attribute of that class, but when you reference a variable, you could be referencing an attribute of the class *or* an external variable.  Therefore, when you say `x = x`, it is the same as saying `C2.x = x`

Comment: yes, x is then a new class variable. What i am wondering is why the evaluation of x that initialized that class variable is evaluated to the surrounding module scope instead of the surrounding function scope. Both `m m` or `a1 a2` would be somehow fine. But why `a1 m`